# Micronaut Data - No bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]

Tags: hibernate, micronaut, micronaut-data

First to mention - I had everything up and running. The only change I made was adding some more repositories to the code.

Then I got:

> 15:47:58.126 [pool-2-thread-4] ERROR
>   i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred:
>   Failed to inject value for parameter [sessionFactory] of class:
>   io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager
>
> Message: No bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] exists for the
>   given qualifier: @Named('default'). Make sure the bean is not disabled
>   by bean requirements (enable trace logging for
>   'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled
>   then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is
>   enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency
>   should be configured as an annotation processor). Path Taken: new
>   HibernateTransactionManager([SessionFactory sessionFactory],DataSource
>   dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor)
>   io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed
>   to inject value for parameter [sessionFactory] of class:
>   io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager

I checked a lot of articles about that, but they all mention dependenices. But i havn't change my dependenices. So i started to investigate. But up to now without success.

I double checked my gradle.build

```
kapt 'io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor:1.0.2'
implementation 'io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa:1.0.2'
implementation 'io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-hikari'
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.12'
testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
```

I also make sure I use the correct versions, but the unit test won't run.

Using Gradle 6.4.1 with micronaut 1.3.5 and obviously data 1.0.2 with jpa.
Any ideas?

Also activated the condition trace, but nothing about the sessionfactory.
Just some spring stuff, but i do not use spring, so therefore i think its okay.

```
15:47:39.037 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.jdbc.spring.$DataSourceTransactionManagerFactory$TransactionAwareDataSourceListener1Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
15:47:39.038 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] is not present
```

Any ideas .. cause that drives me a little crazy :D

Oliver

Comment: Can you provide some code? It is hard to say something without seeing the prject

Comment: Do you expect me to provide around 5k LoC?

Comment: I thinks there is something wrong with the dependencies .. cause it worked and i just added some more repositories .. and the error means to me, that the session factory for default is not there .. so i was wondering how to investigate that, without any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the mistake :-)

```
data class DataX(
        @Id
        val id: String
) {

val yrefs
    get() = _yrefs.toList()

@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH], orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
           mappedBy = "yref") // < this was wrong must be xref
private val _yrefs= mutableListOf<DataY>()
}


data class DataY(
        @Id
        val id: String
) {
val zrefs
    get() = _zrefs.toList()

@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH], orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
           mappedBy = "zref")
private val _zrefs = mutableListOf<DataZ>()

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "x_ref_id")
var xref: DataX? = null
}
```

Comment: And what was the mistake?

Comment: @PatrickFavre look at the comment within the answer ;-) hint: wrong mappedBy

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie with Kotlin and Micronaut, so I'm not sure about it. but Your data class started with lower letter?

For example:

```
@Entity
data class dataBook (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        val id: Long
)
```